# Remote-notifications working when app is in foreground, but not in the background

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a Xamarin.iOS app working that can successfully receive an APNS push notification when the app is running in the foreground.  However, I also want to be able to handle the push notification when the app is running in the background, or not running at all.

This page on Xamarin appears to say that you can indeed do this:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/

I am using the Remote Notifications strategy outlined above.  So I implemented exactly what it said, including changing the info.plist to have Remote Notifications as a background operation.  However, I do not get any calls either in the DidFinishedLaunching, or ReceivedRemoteNotification callbacks when the app is running in the background.  When the app is running in the foreground, everything works just fine.  Needless to say, it's super frustrating.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the code I am using to register for the remote notifications:

```
    public static void NotifyAppStart()
    {
        if (GetRemoteWipePreference())
        {
            if (Utils.CheckOsVersion(8, 0))
            {
                // iOS 8 version

                UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet());  

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            }
            else
            {
                // Only works on iOS 7 and earlier

                UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
            }


        }

    }
```

And here is the PushSharp code I am using to send the push notifications on the server side:

```
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, GetApplePwd()  ));
        push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                                   .ForDeviceToken( token ).WithContentAvailable(1)
                                   .WithCustomItem(msg, device.device_local_guid)  );
```

Side note: There are a few other questions on stack overflow about this general area, but none of them actually are about this issue.

Comment: Are you testing in the Simulator? If yes, there is a bug in the SDK8 Simulator that prevents apps from being truly backgrounded.

Comment: Nope - testing on the device (iPhone 6)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8,0))
        {
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (UIUserNotificationType.Sound |
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, null);

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (settings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
        }
        else
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge |
                UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert);
        }
```

also you need this

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

        var strFormat = new NSString("%@");
        var dt = new NSString(MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class("NSString").Handle, new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("stringWithFormat:").Handle, strFormat.Handle, deviceToken.Handle));
        var newDeviceToken = dt.ToString().Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace(" ", "");
        string sql;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !deviceToken.Equals(newDeviceToken))
        {
            do someting
        }

        if (oldDeviceToken == newDeviceToken) 
        {
            do someting
        } else 
        {
            do something
        }

        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(newDeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
        Console.WriteLine("Device Token: " + newDeviceToken);
    }
```

if your program is foreground you can use like this

```
void processNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching)
    {
        if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
        {
            NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

            string alert = string.Empty;
            string sound = string.Empty;
            int badge = -1;

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
                alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("sound")))
                sound = (aps[new NSString("sound")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("badge")))
            {
                string badgeStr = (aps[new NSString("badge")] as NSObject).ToString();
                int.TryParse(badgeStr, out badge);
            }

            if (!fromFinishedLaunching) 
            {
                if (badge >= 0)
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = badge;

                if (sound == "xx.caf") 
                {
                    UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView ("Dogrular App", alert, null, "Tamam", null);
                    avAlert.Show ();
                }

                if (sound == "yyy.caf") 
                {
                    UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView ("Dogrular App", alert, null, "Tamam", null);
                    avAlert.Show ();

                    NSUrl request = new NSUrl("https://xxx.com");
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback - the problem is that I am trying to get this to work when it is running in the Background, not the Foreground.  Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is your json file consists of `content-available` boolean key is "false"?
Example:

```
{
   "to": "GCM Registration ID",
  "priority":"high",
  "data": {
        "notificationId":123,
        "title":"Spot you!",
        "message": "&lt;font color=\"red\"&gt;&lt;b&gt;Test RED Bold text maybe ?&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Normal second line.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;",
        "photoUrl": "http://babymetal.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/ladybeard-e1427784688234.jpg",
        "badge": 1
  },
   "dry_run" : false,       
   "time_to_live" : 4,
   "content_available" : false
}
```

Above json return should be calling your method

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
```